# jsp forEach Loop through Array of Images and place theme in specific divs

Tags: image, jsp, foreach

I have 60 images and I want to place 3 images in a div each.

```
<c:forEach items="${images}" var="image" varStatus="imgCount">
    <c:if test="${imgCount.count == 3 }">
        <div class="${gridImage.displayposition}">
            <img src="${imagePath}${gridImage.image}" />
        </div>
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Would this be the way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your `c:if` will only be true once: when you're on the third item.  You can use the `mod` or `%` operators in [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) to handle the images in groups of three.  Take care with the varStatus.count property - it's one-based rather than zero-based, so you'd access the next image in the array with `${images[imgCount.count]}`.

```
<c:forEach items="${images}" var="image" varStatus="imgCount">
    <c:if test="${(imgCount.count-1) mod 3 eq 0}">
        <div class="${gridImage.displayposition}">
           <img src="${imagePath}${image}/>
           <img src="${imagePath}${images[imgCount.count]}/>
           <img src="${imagePath}${images[imgCount.count+1]}/>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

You could also use the `step` attribute of the forEach tag and eliminate the need for the `if` statement.  Here, you only create a div every third item.  The count, however, will still continue in the sequence of 1,2,3... (as opposed to 1,4,7...) so you need to multiply the index by three.

```
<c:forEach items="${images}" varStatus="imgCount" step="3">
    <div class="${gridImage.displayposition}">
        <img src="${imagePath}${images[3*(imgCount.count-1)]}"/>
        <img src="${imagePath}${images[3*(imgCount.count-1) + 1]}"/>
        <img src="${imagePath}${images[3*(imgCount.count-1) + 2]}"/>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```